# Calculation based off of previous row (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, logging, time

I'm trying to create an event counter and days since first event counter for some log data. The DataFrame below tracks whether or not an event happened for a group each day. For each group, i need to calculate the number of events that have happened prior and on that date for any date. I also need to calculate the number of days since the first event happened in each group

Starting DF

```
group        date  event
    A  2020-07-16       0
    A  2020-07-17       1
    A  2020-07-18       0
    A  2020-07-19       1
    A  2020-07-20       0
    A  2020-07-21       0
    A  2020-07-22       1
    B  2020-07-16       1
    B  2020-07-17       1
    B  2020-07-18       0
    B  2020-07-19       1
    B  2020-07-20       0
    B  2020-07-21       1
    B  2020-07-22       1
```

Code to generate DF

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
base = datetime.datetime.today()
numdays = 7
date_list = [(base - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).date() for x in range(numdays)]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['group', 'date'])
for group in ['A', 'B']:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'group': group, 'date': date_list})
    df = df.append(tmp)
df = df.sort_values(['group', 'date'])

groupA_events = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
groupB_events = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
events = groupA_events + groupB_events
df['event'] = events
```

Ending DF

```
group        date  event  counter  since_first
    A  2020-07-16      0         0            0
    A  2020-07-17      1         1            0
    A  2020-07-18      0         1            1
    A  2020-07-19      1         2            2
    A  2020-07-20      0         2            3
    A  2020-07-21      0         2            4
    A  2020-07-22      1         3            5
    B  2020-07-16      1         1            0
    B  2020-07-17      1         2            1
    B  2020-07-18      0         2            2
    B  2020-07-19      1         3            3
    B  2020-07-20      0         3            4
    B  2020-07-21      1         4            5
    B  2020-07-22      1         5            6
```

My data is roughly 800k rows (and growing). I found a solution that works (kind of) but has an extremely long execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `groupby` with `cumsum` + `cumcount`

```
df['counter']=df.groupby('group').event.cumsum()
df['since_first']=df[df['counter'].ne(0)].groupby('group')['counter'].cumcount()
df['since_first'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This gave me the error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @claytvh before doing above , check do df=df.reset_index()

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cumsum` to get the counter. The days since can be obtained by masking then `transforming` to the first day where there is an event within each group. This is useful as if your dates aren't continuous it will still properly calculate the time difference. (`clip` so anything before is considered 0)

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby('group').agg(counter=('event', 'cumsum'))

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s_first = df['date'].where(df['event'].eq(1)).groupby(df['group']).transform('first')

df['days_since'] = (df['date'] - s_first).dt.days.clip(lower=0)
```

---

```
  group       date  event  counter  days_since
6     A 2020-07-16      0        0           0
5     A 2020-07-17      1        1           0
4     A 2020-07-18      0        1           1
3     A 2020-07-19      1        2           2
2     A 2020-07-20      0        2           3
1     A 2020-07-21      0        2           4
0     A 2020-07-22      1        3           5
6     B 2020-07-16      1        1           0
5     B 2020-07-17      1        2           1
4     B 2020-07-18      0        2           2
3     B 2020-07-19      1        3           3
2     B 2020-07-20      0        3           4
1     B 2020-07-21      1        4           5
0     B 2020-07-22      1        5           6
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much!!!! Adding a layer of complexity: What if I had 2 events (event1 and event2). How convert s_first into being the first time that event2 happened after an event1 already happened for that group?

Comment: @claytvh You can change the mask you send to `where`. If you take the `cummax` of event_1 that will forward fill it after the first 1, so you would use `df['date'].where(df.groupby('group')['event1'].cummax().eq(1) & df['event2'].eq(1))` and follow with the same groupby and all other steps.